# Is there a way to customize style of Bing Maps PolyLine?

Tags: win-universal-app, bing-maps, uwp-maps

Is it possible to add custom styling to polyline in Windows UWP maps control?  For example can you make a gradient on the line so one side is bold and then fades to the other side, or maybe make the edges of the line blurred.

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use [MapPolyLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mappolyline.aspx) class? Can we bind an image  which already has these effects to the map?

Comment: @Sunteen I suppose not, but whatever alternative there is, I must be able to set the position of the line dynamically at run time based on a series of geo points.  Currently my polyline points are bound to an observable collection of BasicGeoPoint defined in my viewmodel.

Comment: Bind a image also can define its location. please see scenario3 of [MapControl official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MapControl/cs).

Answer (score 3):

The UWP map control is a native C++ control and rendering of polylines, polygons, and MapIcons are done using native C++. As such most XAML styling functionalities are not an option. The MapPolyline class allows you to customize the stroke color, stroke thickness and the make the line a dashed line. Documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mappolyline.aspx

The color must be a Color and not a brush.